# Fix Formatting/CSS Style Error

Tags: html, css, formatting

I took the nav bar / header from this page: http://specialistleague.com/cinema and attempted to put it on this page: http://specialistleague. com/recruiting

Here is my attempt: [**Link**](http://t.comuf.com/recruiting/)

As you may tell, the scrollbar got pushed to the left along side the PDF document and the footer at the bottom got stretched. I need everything to be the same on the original page I just needed the header / nav bar there.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your html/css classes are slightly off. Remove the containing .row div, as well as the .row class from the inner div. Change:

```
...
</header>

<!-- Remove containing .row div (below) -->
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="row" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none; width: 100%;">
        <iframe class="pdf" src="pdf.php"></iframe>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

to:

```
...
</header>

<!-- Here, we have removed the containing .row div -->
<div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; border: none; width: 100%;">
    <iframe class="pdf" src="pdf.php"></iframe>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Please see it now. It messed some things up.

Comment: Hi, I have updated and tested my example – it appears to be working now.

Comment: Ok, it has fixed the scrollbar issue, but the bottom footer issue is still occuring :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you have commented "cinema.css" link in head because of this issue.

The problem here, is the wide use of .row class in the page. The attributes for row class in cinema.css is causing the problem.

Sol-

- Best thing you can do is replace all .row class(4 occurrence) in this page with new class.
- or you can define specific attributes to .row class for this particular page,    something as follows.

  ```
  #pagename .row {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  }
  ```

---

Once done with above, you may have to work on css to fix the properties of input item as well.

Hope this helps :)